# jwt generated token decode problem in python

Tags: python, flask, jwt

I am trying to decode a jwt encoded token

this is my code

```
 token = jwt.encode({'public_id': user.public_id, 'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + 
 datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)}, app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
 
 decodetoken = token.decode('UTF-8')}
```

**This shows the error**

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: looks like token is a string. maybe look at jwt.decode(token

Answer (score 0):

To see the decoded token you could do this:

```
import jwt
import datetime
key = app.config['SECRET_KEY']
vdate = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
token = jwt.encode({'public_id': user.public_id, 'exp': vdate}, key)
print(jwt.decode(token, key, 'HS256')
```